I'm trying to create a search box with a<i class="fa fa-search"> icon in the search box
I'm trying to show WordPress search box into my website where i am trying to show an icon in the search box
<?php get_search_form(); ?>
HTML Form
<form role="search" method="get" class="header-search-form" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>"> 
    <label> 
        <input type="search" class="search-field"  placeholder="SEARCH" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" name="s" title="Search for:" />                               <i class="fa fa-search"></i> 
    </label>
</form>


And This CSS

/* Style the search form */
.header-search-form {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; /* Center the search bar in the header */
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 5px;
}

.header-search-form input[type="search"] {
    border: 2px solid #bf2137; /* Border color */
    border-radius: 20px; /* Rounded corners */
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color: #bf2137; /* Text color */
    font-size: 16px;
}

.header-search-form input[type="search"]::placeholder {
    color: #bf2137; /* Placeholder text color */
}

.header-search-form input[type="submit"] {
    display: none; /* Hide the default search button */
}


Everything is perfect fine except the fact that the () fa-fa icon is not showing in the box.
I am basically looking to show fa fa search icon with in the search box.

Posting your php is of limited use, given that your question is fundamentally [tag:html] and [tag:css]; could you share the HTML that's received by the client after the php is generated?

The issue I note your search icon is being placed outside of search input field. This code is working from my side like this
[enter image description here]1
HTML File
         <form role="search" method="get" class="header-search-form">
                <label>
                    <div class="search-input-container">
                        <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="Search" name="s" title="Search for:" />
                        <i class="fa fa-search search-icon"></i>
                    </div>
                </label>
            </form>

CSS File
     .header-search-form {
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
                margin: 0 auto;
                padding: 5px;
            }
    
            .search-input-container {
                position: relative;
                width: 100%;
            }
    
            .search-field {
                width: 100%;
                padding: 10px 15px;
                padding-right: 40px;
                border: 2px solid #bf2137;
                border-radius: 20px;
                color: #bf2137;
                font-size: 16px;
            }
    
            .search-field::placeholder {
                color: #bf2137;
            }
    
            .search-icon {
                position: absolute;
                right: 25px;
                top: 50%;
                transform: translateY(-50%);
                color: #bf2137;
                font-size: 16px;
            }
    
            .header-search-form input[type="submit"] {
                display: none;
            }

Hopefully this will work from your side, Thanks
